# Which assemblies should I emit to trace asp.net web-api exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, trace

I want to be able to see what's going wrong when my application crashes in iisexpress rather than in the visual studio debugger.

For a [WCF application](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2012/06/simple-steps-to-enable-tracing-in-wcf.html) you might trace assemblies like these:

- System.ServiceModel
- System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging
- System.ServiceModel.IdentityModel
- System.ServiceModel.Activation
- System.Runtime.Serialization
- System.IO.Log

I'm assuming you should listen to different assemblies for an asp.net web-api. If that's correct, which ones?

Comment: Emitting an assembly? Do you mean reference?

Comment: Sorry. That was a bit unclear. Updated the question using the words trace and listen. (Was trying to use the terminology of the blog I linked.)

Comment: All you do with assemblies is 'reference' them. You don't trace them or emit them. You can add a trace listener to a namespace or type, but this happens at runtime.

Comment: No, I'm not looking to find out which assemblies to reference. They're allready referenced (otherwise my application wouldn't run). But I have a LOT of references, and I would like to know for which ones I need to add a trace listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Web API all you need to do for tracing the "internals" off the framework is to use an implementation of ITraceWriter.

An example using system.diagnostics is avilable on nuget - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing